# How do I calculate centroid of a polygon if the vertices of the polygon are given?

Tags: c, c++11, math, geometry

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon

I visited the above link and tried to implement the formula to formulate the centroid of a non-self-intersecting closed polygon defined by n vertices (x0,y0), (x1,y1), ..., (xn−1,yn−1).

For instance if the co-ordinates are : `(0,1)`,`(1,0)`,`(-1,0)` and `(0,-1)`, the resulting co-ordinates of centroid should be :
`0.00 0.00`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t,points;       
    scanf("%d",&points);
    pair<float,float>p[points];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<points;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f %f",&p[i].first,&p[i].second);

    }
    float ar,x,y;
    for(i=0;i<points-1;i++)
    {
         ar+=(p[i].first*p[i+1].second-(p[i+1].first*p[i].second));
         x+=((p[i].first+p[i+1].first)*ar);
         y+=((p[i].second+p[i+1].second)*ar);
    }
    x/=(3*ar);
    y/=(3*ar);
    printf("%.2f %.2f\n",x,y);
}
```

However when I run the above code for the given co-ordinates the resulting co-ordinates of centroid are :

`-1. -1.`

Comment: I would initialize `ar`, `x`, and `y` to zero before using `+=`.

Comment: from the wiki article. - `The centroid of a non-self-intersecting closed polygon defined` The points you entered are a self intersecting polygon FYI ... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%280%2C1%29%2C%281%2C0%29%2C%28-1%2C0%29+and+%280%2C-1%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following issues:

1. `ar`, `x`, and `y` are not initialized.
2. The computation is wrong in the lines:

   ```
   x+=((p[i].first+p[i+1].first)*ar);
   y+=((p[i].second+p[i+1].second)*ar);
   ```
3. You are missing one iteration of the loop by using:

   ```
   for(i=0;i<points-1;i++)
   ```

Here's a version of the function that works for me:

```
int main()
{
   int points;       
   scanf("%d",&points);
   pair<float,float>p[points];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<points;i++)
   {
      scanf("%f %f",&p[i].first,&p[i].second);
   }

   float ar = 0.0;
   float x = 0.0;
   float y = 0.0;

   for(i=0;i<points;i++)
   {
      // This allows wrap-around when are you dealing with 
      // the last point in the list.
      int j = (i+1)%points;

      float common = (p[i].first*p[j].second - p[j].first*p[i].second);
      ar += common;
      x+=(p[i].first+p[j].first)*common;
      y+=(p[i].second+p[j].second)*common;
   }

   ar *= 0.5;
   x /= (6*ar);
   y /= (6*ar);

   printf("area: %.2f, xc: %.2f, yc: %.2f\n", ar, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of thing to change in your code :

- As noticed by @R Sahu , `ar`, `x` and `y` must be initialized to zero before the `for` loop. Otherwise, the output may be wrong or it may change over different runs.
- At iteration `j`, `ar` is

[image: eq]

So `x+=(p[i].first+p[i+1].first)*ar;` is wrong since it must be :

[image: eq2]

- Take a close look at the lines after the formula on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon)

> In these formulas, the vertices are assumed to be numbered in order of their occurrence along the polygon's perimeter, and the vertex ( xn, yn ) is assumed to be the same as ( x0, y0 ).

Since the last point is not equal to the first point in your program, the output is wrong. And nothing ensures that the points are entered in order of their occurrence along the polygon's perimeter.

Here is a code compiled by `g++ main.cpp -o main -Wall`. The option `-Wall` enables all warnings... It's a good practice to use it to debug a code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int points;
    //scanf("%d",&points);
    points=4;
    pair<float,float>p[points];
    int i;
    /* for(i=0;i<points;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f %f",&p[i].first,&p[i].second);
    } */
    p[0].first=1;p[0].second=0;
    p[1].first=0;p[1].second=1;
    p[2].first=-1;p[2].second=0;
    p[3].first=0;p[3].second=-1;

    float ar=0,x=0,y=0,temp;
    for(i=0;i<points-1;i++)
    {
        temp=p[i].first*p[i+1].second-p[i+1].first*p[i].second;
        ar+=temp;
        x+=(p[i].first+p[i+1].first)*temp;
        y+=(p[i].second+p[i+1].second)*temp;
    }
    temp=p[points-1].first*p[0].second-p[0].first*p[points-1].second;
    ar+=temp;
    x+=(p[points-1].first+p[0].first)*temp;
    y+=(p[points-1].second+p[0].second)*temp;

    x/=(3*ar);
    y/=(3*ar);
    printf("%.6f %.6f\n",x,y);
}
```

Notice that by testing `(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)`, the correctness of `ar` is not ensured...